# linear algebra - determine unknown value that will allow for $v∈\text{Span} \ S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Screenshot of [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbhAX.jpg), transcribed:

> You are given $v$ and a span of vectors. In the first box, enter $1,2,$ or 3 to describe which of the scenarios below holds true.
>
> 1) There is no value of $a$ that will allow for $v \in \operatorname{Span} S$.
>
> 2) All values of $a$ will allow for $v \in \operatorname{Span} S$
>
> 3) There is one unique value of $a$ that will allow for $v \in \operatorname{Span}
> S$
>
> $\quad$ a) ____ $ : v=\left[\begin{array}{c}-4 \\ 4 \\ 4 \\ a\end{array}\right]$ and $S$ contains $\left[\begin{array}{c}-1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c}-2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{array}\right]$
>
> The value of $a$ is: _____ (if you select option $1$, or option $2,$ then fill this box with $0 .$ If you select option $3$, then fill this box with the value of $a$).

So I'm asked to answer a series of questions following this format but I'm stuck on figuring out how I would actually calculate the value of $a$. I think I'm supposed to put $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ infront of each of the 3 vectors and check for a solution using RREF by inserting all the values to form a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

Like for example in the question in the picture, I'm confident the answer is 3 for the first blank (that there is one unique value which will allow for $v∈\text{Span} \ S$). I just have no idea as to how I would answer the second part of the question - to find the value of $a$. I would appreciate some help or a push in the right direction.

Comment: When in doubt go back to definitions: what does it mean for a vector to be an element of the span of a set of vectors? Can you turn this condition into a system of linear equations? How many solutions does this system have for various values of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to test when there is a linear combination of the three given vectors that produces our semi-unknown vector. That is, we are solving:
$$x\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + z\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -4 \\ 4 \\ 4 \\ a \end{bmatrix}.$$
This is a system of $4$ equations in $3$ unknowns, whose augmented matrix comes to be
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-1 & -1 & -2 & -4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & a
\end{array}\right].$$
Now, all you need to do is row reduce this matrix. I'm not going to do it for you; this is something you should practice for yourself. Row reduction isn't really any harder; just remember to take the augmented column along for the ride as usual. For example, if we add row $3$ to row $4$, we get the equivalent matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-1 & -1 & -2 & -4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & a + 4
\end{array}\right].$$

Inevitably, the last row will contain $0$s except for the augmented column, which may or may not depend on $a$. If it depends on $a$, find the values of $a$ for which this expression becomes $0$. These will be the values of $a$ for which the system is consistent and the vector lies in the span of the other $3$.

Otherwise, you may find that all the $a$s cancel and there is a constant $0$ next to the row of $0$s. In this case, the system is always consistent, and hence the vector is in the span regardless of the value of $a$.

On the other hand, you may find that all the $a$s cancel, and there is a non-zero constant next to the row of $0$s. This means the system is never consistent, and the vector never lies in the span, regardless of the value of $a$.